# Is it possible to download an entire directory over FTP?

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am using the following batch file code to download a single file from the FTP directory. If I have folder named "Presentation" in this directory. Can I modify the code so that it downloads the entire folder?

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName= 
Set _UserName=FTPUser
Set _Password=enter4FTP
Set _LocalFolder= C:\Users
Set _Filename= test.txt
Set _ScriptFile=ftp1
:: Create script
>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo get %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
Del "%_ScriptFile%"
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line:

```
Set _Filename= test.txt
```

replace the filename with `Presentation` or the directory you want, and in the following line:

```
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo get %_Filename%
```

replace `get` with `mget`.

Comment: when I do this I see a prompt "mget_includes?

Comment: Looks like its asking if I want to download each folder is there a way to stop prompts and just transfer?

Comment: Turn off interactive prompts - `type FTP /?` for help